# Auth.GoogleSignInApi as GoogleAuthUtil replacement for google plus sign in

Tags: android, google-plus-signin, android-account, google-identity

My goal is to log into a BaaS with the Google plus sdk, the BaaS requires a tokenId via `googleSignInAccount.getIdToken()` and an accessToken.

`GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(activity, accountName, scopes);` is depreciated, and was used to get the accessToken.

`GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken(activity, token);` is also depreciated.

What is the alternative way to get the accessToken and invalidate(is invalidation needed now)?

I am aware of and have tried:
`GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Context, Account, String);`
and
`GoogleAuthUtil.clearToken(activity, token);`

Account seems to require a first part permission(thus not an option) Ex. `account = new Account(googleSignInAccount.getEmail(), "com.google");` nor do I know if clear is synonymous with invalidate(seems to work with the depreciated method however, I don't know the repercussions), or if there are some other call/api's to use.

Like from:`com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google developer site has a page on migrating from GoogleAuthUtil.getToken

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/migration-guide

This code is no longer complaiming of using depreciated API

```
    private void loginInBackendless(final GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult: try login to backendless");

    //final MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)this.getActivity();
    //final String accountName = acct.getEmail();
    final String scopes = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PLUS_ME + " " + Scopes.PROFILE + " " + Scopes.EMAIL;
    final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = this;
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String token = null;
            try {
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(fragmentActivity, acct.getAccount(), scopes);
                GoogleAuthUtil.clearToken(fragmentActivity, token);
                handleAccessTokenInBackendless(acct.getIdToken(), token);
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return token;
        }
    };

    task.execute();
}
```